# Is it a mistake to use the App-class as TypeInTargetAssembly

Tags: wpf

Is it a mistake to use the `App`-class for defining the `TypeInTargetAssembly` of a `ComponentResourceKey`. Is there some rule for the selection of the target class or is it absolutely not important which class one takes?

The only important thing I have figured out is, that the class is stable and does disappear once, because it is no needed any longer. But are there more thouhgs on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its important (other than the fact that its your class and thus you don't conflict with anyone else).